# dynamic rowspan in html

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I have below html code and I iwant to set its rowspan equal to the length of data as in for loop. I dont have much knowledge about html so can you please provide me with one line of code which sets rowspan dynamically.

```html
 <td style="border:1px solid rgb(0,0,0);overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:rgb(111,168,220);font-weight:bold;white-space:normal;text-align:center" rowspan="2" colspan="1">
                              <div style="max-height:65px">Tasks for Today</div>
                           </td>
                           <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(0,0,0) rgb(0,0,0) rgb(0,0,0) rgb(204,204,204);overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:top;background-color:rgb(111,168,220);font-weight:bold;text-align:center">Task</td>
                          <? for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { ?>
                           <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid;border-color:rgb(0,0,0) rgb(0,0,0) rgb(0,0,0) rgb(204,204,204);overflow:hidden;padding:2px 3px;vertical-align:top;background-color:rgb(111,168,220);font-weight:bold;text-align:center"><?=data[i].task?>.</td>
                            <? } ?>
```

Comment: Do you want to make the table using javascript? Depending on the dataArray.

Comment: Im evaluating it from JavaScript function and passed data array from there. And I want the rowspan to be equal to length of array.

Comment: This looks like `PHP` mixed with `JavaScript`

Comment: I dont know the for loop works for me but all I need is to change rowspan.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Javascript Jquery:

```js
let dataSet=[{emp:"Palash",address:'address 1'},{emp:"Kanti",address:'address 2'},{emp:"Bachar",address:'address 2'}];

let tableTr="";
dataSet.map((r,index)=>{
    if(index==0){
      tableTr=tableTr+`<tr>
                          <td rowspan="${dataSet.length}">Company Title </td>
                          <td>${r.emp}</td>
                          <td>${r.address}</td>
                      </r>`;
    }else{
    tableTr=tableTr+`<tr>
                          <td>${r.emp}</td>
                          <td>${r.address}</td>
                      </tr>`
    }

});

 $('#table tbody').append(tableTr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
<thead>
<th>Company Name </th>
<th>EMP Name </th>
<th>Address </th>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```